# Which one is correct to use question sentence?

Tags: american-english

Which one is correct sentence?

1. Does most Amazon people doing well at English like you?
2. Are most Amazon people good at English like you?
3. What else?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first sentence is incorrect. "People" is a plural form.
For the same structure, the correct sentence should be like **"Do most Amazon people do well at English like you?"**
The second sentence "Are most Amazon people good at English like you?", is correct.